# Removing White Spaces in a Python String

Tags: python

The general question is to remove all extra spaces from a python string so that there is only one space between each word, and no spaces at the beginning or end of the string.

For example,
'  Hello  to the   world  ' will return as 'Hello to the world'

We are not allowed to use the split command, or any commands besides basic string operators (length and concantenation) and if and while commands.

I have written my program so that it removes the spaces at the beginning of the string as well as extra spaces between words, however, if I have even one space after the last word in the input string the program returns an error that "index[i] is out of range".

Here is my program:

```
def cleanstring (s):
    i=0
    while s[i]==' ':
        i=i+1
    s=s[i:len(s)]
    i=0
    while i<len(s):
        if s[i]!=' ':
            i=i+1
        else:
            if i<len(s) and s[i]==' ':
                i=i+1
            if s[i]==' ' and i+1<len(s):
                s=s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)]
                i=0
    return(s)
```

Hopefully someone can help me determine what is wrong with it. It seems as though I've tried everything but I know that it's just my inexperience with python.

Comment: Vandalising the post is not the way to deal with issues like this. Contact SE directly using the "contact us" form to get the post removed.

Comment: Hey Chris, I contacted SE using the "contact us" form but I need the post removed as soon as possible. I have been told I do have to manually delete it because, as I said, code of conduct issues. I'm not sure if it can be described as "vandalism" if it is my own post that I created, but I have been told that I must delete it. I'm hoping the thread itself will be removed once SE has had a change to view my message.

Comment: It's still vandalism. When you posted the question you gave SE the right to use the post. While you can request that it's removed you can't vandalise it in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your i is in range in one more place. Give this a shot:

```
def cleanstring(s):
    i=0
    while s[i]==' ':
        i=i+1
    s=s[i:len(s)]
    i=0
    while i<len(s):
        if s[i]==' ':
            if (i+1)<len(s) and s[i+1]==' ':
                s=s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)]
            else:
                i=i+1
        else:
            i=i+1
    if s[len(s)-1]==' ':
        s=s[0:len(s)-1]
    return(s)
```

Comment: If I change it to (i+1)<len(s) it now is null and doesn't return any string at all unfortunately.

Comment: Hold on I'm running it and I'll update in a couple minutes

Comment: @pythonrookie try this now

Comment: Thank you so much this worked like a charm. I really appreciate the help, you have no idea how much stress you just saved me from.

Comment: s[len(s)-1] can be s[-1], s[0:len(s)-1] can be s[:-1]

Comment: Actually it could be written as s[-1] but this way is a little more verbose and easier to understand for a beginner. +1 for the pythonic way of doing it though

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an easy and clever fix. Change

```
if s[i]==' ' and i+1<len(s):
```

to...

```
if i<len(s) and s[i]==' ':
```

This works because Python short-circuits `and` if a falsy value is encountered at any point. This means that after `i<len(s)` evaluates to False and Python encounters `and`, it will immediately move on to the `elif` or `else` clauses if there are any. Thus, the second half is never evaluated so there is no `IndexError`.

Now, this program does not work perfectly. There *are* other problems with it, but as this is a homework assignment, I am reluctant to offer any more help. Aside from this hint: you need another while loop.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. The program is still null and returns no string unfortunately.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The program (almost) works on my computer and it *does* return a string. Perhaps you need to `print` the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your implementation structure, with the required changes:

```
def cleanstring (s):
    i=0
    while s[i]==' ':
        i=i+1
    s=s[i:len(s)]
    i=0
    while i<len(s):
        if s[i]!=' ':
            i=i+1
        else:
            if i<len(s) and s[i]==' ':
                i=i+1
            if i<len(s) and s[i]==' ':
                s=s[0:i]+s[i+1:len(s)]
                i=0
    if s[-1] == ' ':
        s = s[:-1]
    return(s)
```

What is changed is:

```
if s[i]==' ' and i+1<len(s):
```

To:

```
if i<len(s) and s[i]==' ':
```

But this will keep one more space at the end, so

```
if s[-1] == ' ':
            s = s[:-1]
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine.
Check it out.
The repr() just gives the string in quotes, in order to see the actual number of spaces before and after the words.

```
def cleanstring (s):
    hit_letter = False
    space_counter = 0
    tmp = list()
    for letter in s:
        if letter.isalpha():
            space_counter = 0
            hit_letter = True
            tmp.append(letter)
            print letter
        elif hit_letter:
            space_counter += 1
            if space_counter < 2:
                tmp.append(letter)
    return ''.join(tmp[:-1])


print repr(cleanstring('  Hi to the  world '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some recursion

```
def cleanString(word):
    if word[0]==" ":
        if len(word)>1:
            return cleanString(word[1:])
        return word[1:]
    elif len(word)>1:
        return word[0]+cleanString(word[1:])
    return word
print cleanString("   abcd  ") == "abcd" # True
print cleanString("   abcd  ") # abcd
```